# Jersey 1.19, TomEE+ 1.74. Web.xml Url-Pattern is not working correctly

Tags: java, jersey, web.xml, apache-tomee, url-pattern

Using: Jersey 1.19, TomEE Plus 1.74
I can access the same controller method via two different urls.

```
http://localhost:8080/hello
http://localhost:8080/rest/hello
```

web.xml:

```
<init-param>
   <param-name>
      com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
   </param-name>
   <paramvalue>
        mif.ubermensch.labanorogiraite.presentation.controllers
    </param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LabanoroGiraite</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Controller:

```
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String Hello(){
        return "Hello, Restful world!";
    }
}
```

Additions were made to TomEE system.properties based on result found on stackoverfow

```
 openejb.api.javax.ws.rs.Path.validation=false
 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.cdi.lookupExtensionInBeanManager=true
```

Without these two, accessing a url with the /rest/ prefix would cause an excepion:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com].
```

How to restrict the access only through the /api/* url-pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't mention which flavor of tomee you are using but if a distribution providing jaxrs (-jaxrs or -plus) you will need to add disabled=true in conf/conf.d/cxf-rs.properties.